# How to change the phpMyAdmin root password via a PHP query script

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, system-administration

I have a question on whether or not I can use a PHP script to change the phpMyAdmin root password. I am in the process of starting a small hosting/sass business, and one thing I need to do is get this working if you have a better solution for this, let me know.

I took a look at this query, but you can only run this when you have already logged in to the phpMyAdmin panel.
`SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('yourpassword');`

I basically want to be able to run this query, but in a PHP file.

Expected result: Once this PHP script is ran, it will change the phpMyAdmin root password.

How would I be able to do this? Is it possible?
If you need more information please let me know, I will get back to you as soon as I can.

Thank you

Comment: Just write a PHP script that connects to the MySQL server and executes the query, using either `mysqli` or `PDO`. Just like any other PHP script that uses MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar Wouldn’t that have to be a connection to a specific database though? Is there a database that stores all phpMyAdmin user data (root, root password, etc.)?

Comment: phpMyAdmin doesn't have its own user table, it uses the MySQL `mysql` database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution

I made a connection to the mysql server and proceeded to change the root password. A simple solution that costed me a few hours.

```
$conn = new mysqli(IP,MySQL Username,Password);
$conn->query("SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('password');");
$conn->query("FLUSH PRIVILEGES;");
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score -1):

try this! (remember this code is for localhost only).

$query = "SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('your_root_password')";
mysql_query($query);

Comment: Ok thank you, can this be possible with a php script that is not on the local host? If not, can this be done possibly with a bash script?

Comment: you should use root@% instead of root@localhost in your realhost.Actually you can use root@% for both local and real host

Comment: `mysql_query` is dead. It can't be used any more.

Comment: You should use `mysqli` or `PDO`. The `mysql_XXX` functions were deprecated years ago, and removed completely in PHP 7.x.

Answer (score -1):

phpMyAdmin doesn't have its own user table, it uses the MySQL `mysql` database because at the end of the day phpMyAdmin is just another MySQL client.

You have two options to change passwords there:

- Use [`mysqladmin`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqladmin.html).
- Use the correct [`SET PASSWORD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html) command. **DO NOT** use `PASSWORD(...)` here as that sets your password to be, literally, some scrambled (hashed) version of your password. Let MySQL do the hashing for you.

In order to change the password you need to know the current password. This makes scripting it difficult unless you have some place to easily change the password *external to the script itself*. I'd suggest an *INI file* which can be [easily parsed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).

That being said, phpMyAdmin is not always the best solution, especially when free tools like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) exist. phpMyAdmin is a potential security risk, and a severe one if people use weak passwords like `db123`.